# Meaning of "Break out of the bubble"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What is the meaning of the expression **break out of the bubble**? I found this phrase in [newspaper](https://www.thehindu.com/podcast/how-do-you-find-your-favourite-podcasts/article24841307.ece). Below is paragraph where it being used.

> Keyword searches on the web might be a better way to **break out of the
>   bubble** and find the wider range of podcasts, particularly if one is
>   looking for a non-fiction programming.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

[**bubble**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bubble)

> a situation in which you only experience things that you expect or find easy to deal with, for example opinions you agree with, or people who are similar to you

In the previous paragraph of the [referred article](https://www.thehindu.com/podcast/how-do-you-find-your-favourite-podcasts/article24841307.ece) such **bubble** is described

> many of **these routes take us to more of the same thing, or the same
>   shade of different**. The politics and the aesthetic tend to fall within
>   a narrow — and comfortable — part of the preference spectrum.

**Breaking out of the bubble** is obtaining podcasts' suggestions from **outside your circle** (friends in Facebook, people you follow in Twitter, blogs you usually read, ...)

Notice that **bubble** is not a synonym for any **problem**. It's a specific **situation** whose details are explained in the dictionary entry. **Breaking out the bubble** does not mean **solving any problem** that you may face, that situation may not be even a problem for you. I've described what that expression means in your context.

Comment: @RubioRic- Thank you for answer. Could you tell me why you used second paragraph? many of these...

Comment: @Arvindraja The second paragraph is taken from an article that contains yours https://www.thehindu.com/podcast/how-do-you-find-your-favourite-podcasts/article24841307.ece

Comment: @Arvindraja Is not the one that you have read? Please include the right link in your post

Comment: @RubioRic- Oh nice. Exactly same article I was reading. I was out of context & didn't notice that. So break out of the bubble means solving problem. Here word bubble referring to an issue/concern.

Comment: @Arvindraja No, "breaking the bubble" is not a metaphor for "solving the problem". Bubble means a specific situation, breaking out of the bubble is what I've explained above.

Answer (score 1):

There's an allegorical saying that goes like this:

> To live in a bubble

It means "to live in an isolated environment, usually of your own choice".
Hence "to break out of the bubble" in your case refers to finding a way to get your hands on more podcasts.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I did not get proper meaning & use of given phrase.

Comment: @Arvindraja I would equate the bubble to your comfort zone, when you break out of the bubble, you step outside your comfort zone, you attempt something new in order to attain something you want.